# add custom notification for buddypress related to woocommerce

Tags: notifications, woocommerce, buddypress

i am new here i am developing a plugin for WordPress and i need some help from you :) i want to add custom notification to Buddypress and this is how it works: when i add a product by woocommerce , a notification appear for users .i read so many article but i don't understand what i have to do. please tell me what exactly i have to do. i read this articles but nothing ! https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/function-examples/bp_notifications_add_notification/ http://androoha.com/web-design-tuts/80-custom-notifications-buddypress-en thank you for your attention

Comment: is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bp_notification on save_post action hook whenever woocommerce product has added

You can loop over **bp_notifications_add_notification** function to send nonfiction to multiple users

```
function product_add_notification( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
      $slug = 'product';

      if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
            return;
      }
      // $invited_user_id would be user_id to whom we are sending notification
      bp_notifications_add_notification( array(
            'user_id'           => $invited_user_id,
            'item_id'           => $post_id,
      ) );
  }
  add_action( 'save_post', 'product_add_notification', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: @mohammad_hasani Please accept this answer if it is helped you.